# Check if the corresponding elements in two different list of dataframes are equal

Tags: r, list, dataframe, if-statement

I have a two separate list of dataframes.
The first list of dataframe is `lst1`

```
$`1`
 [1] 8.523769e-05 6.615035e-05 1.177740e-04 1.173578e-04 8.798214e-05 6.328218e-05 4.768889e-05 3.658710e-05
 [9] 1.294623e-05 1.179838e-06 1.010590e-06 5.204994e-07 2.128048e-06 6.876634e-06 6.011750e-06 5.160903e-05
[17] 5.318722e-05 1.029438e-04 1.173397e-04

$`2`
 [1] 9.206525e-05 1.472897e-04 2.650569e-04 2.313355e-04 1.984725e-04 1.645034e-04 1.456210e-04 6.768821e-05
 [9] 4.187954e-05 4.823388e-05 4.279551e-05 4.191838e-05 5.642628e-05 8.094616e-05 1.013678e-04 2.232152e-04
[17] 2.255819e-04 2.358519e-04 2.645930e-04

$`3`
 [1] 0.0003263243 0.0009461198 0.0011599270 0.0009269332 0.0007441947 0.0021864953 0.0023836129 0.0019477809
 [9] 0.0006745046 0.0004784856 0.0005603616 0.0005089821 0.0005140971 0.0001900949 0.0002591991 0.0004950753
[17] 0.0005729661 0.0006404173 0.0007336286
```

The second list of dataframe is `lst2`

```
$`1`
 [1] 8.523769e-05 6.595870e-04 1.434451e-03 1.267164e-03 1.140118e-03 1.037180e-03 1.007861e-03 7.581415e-04
 [9] 1.294623e-05 1.179838e-06 1.010590e-06 5.204994e-07 2.128048e-06 5.297516e-04 5.515672e-04 5.510878e-04
[17] 5.635382e-04 6.966825e-04 7.091103e-04

$`2`
 [1] 1.335764e-03 1.534220e-03 7.072944e-04 2.313355e-04 1.984725e-04 1.645034e-04 1.456210e-04 6.768821e-05
 [9] 4.187954e-05 4.823388e-05 4.279551e-05 4.191838e-05 5.642628e-05 8.094616e-05 1.013678e-04 2.232152e-04
[17] 2.255819e-04 8.953077e-04 9.560716e-04

$`3`
 [1] 0.0003263243 0.0009461198 0.0011599270 0.0023806365 0.0030363610 0.0033131562 0.0027954296 0.0016694135
 [9] 0.0002395362 0.0002608362 0.0005603616 0.0005089821 0.0005140971 0.0001900949 0.0002591991 0.0004950753
[17] 0.0007601880 0.0009152222 0.0010781228
```

I am trying to check if the corresponding elements in `lst1` is equal to `lst2`.
If the elements are equal in the list it should return `x`, if not it should return `o`.

The solution for such example can be

```
$`1`
[1] 0 x x x x .....and so on
...
```

I tried writing a function to do that.

```
checkreferencevalue<- function (ref,attk){ifelse(ref == attk, 'x','o')}
```

But I cannot seem to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
c("o", "x")[mapply(identical, lst1, lst2) + 1]
```

Reproducible demo:

```
lst1 = list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9)
lst2 = list(1:3, c(5, 5, 5), 7:9)
c("o", "x")[mapply(identical, lst1, lst2) + 1]
# [1] "x" "o" "x"
```

For element-wise comparison within the lists:

```
mapply(\(x, y) c("o", "x")[(x == y) + 1], lst1, lst2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "x" "x" "x"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "o" "x" "o"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "x" "x" "x"
```

Comment: Sorry I might not have been clear. for your example, I wanted to compare each example in ```lst1``` with its corresponding element in ```lst2```.
The solution would be something like:

```
[[1]]
"o" "o" "o"
[[2]]
"x" "o" "x"
```
and so on.
Thank you!!

Comment: Updated - should work now. Next time it would help if you make a simple example (my `1:3` is much easier to see what's going on than your `8.523769e-05 6.615035e-05 1.177740e-04...`) and provide the sample data in a copy/pasteable way.